# Using API of Node.js-module OrbitDB in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, node.js, p2p, ipfs

I need to use OrbitDB (https://github.com/orbitdb/orbit-db). However, I haven’t yet found how to call API methods from this NPM module in Java. Maybe there is at least some kind of wrapper for this?

Comment: Atleast tell us what you have tried and what problem you facing

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Most likely I will use [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8) (run the V8 virtual machine in the Android application). I know this is a crutch, but at least that is it.

Comment: Could you please detail what you did? How do you embed OrbitDB in your Android app in the first place ? How do you access it's API in practice? Is there a public project or page where we can find your work?

Comment: @VictorPaléologue I gave up this venture (and my project as well), because J2V8 doesn't compile with modern versions of NodeJS. But I just found new project with similar idea: https://github.com/caoccao/Javet, you can try it.